# Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers such that $|2z - w| = 25$, $|z + 2w| = 5$, and $|z + w| = 2$. Find $|z|$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

> Let $z$ and $w$ be complex numbers such that $|2z - w| = 25$, $|z + 2w| = 5$, and $|z + w| = 2$. Find $|z|$.

I found the answer $\sqrt{\frac{243}{3}}$, using $z\overline{z} = |z|^2$ and expanding out equations, but that was marked wrong.

Comment: btw $\sqrt{243/3}=9$

Comment: Why do you think $|z|^2 = 243/3$?  Um, fonfonx???  $\sqrt{243/3} = \sqrt{81} = 9$?

Comment: Please include the problem statement in the body of your Question (not only in the title).  The body of the Question gives you space to explain how you arrived at your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Edited

---

$$\begin{cases}(2z-w)(2\overline{z}-\overline{w})=625\\(z+2w)(\overline{z}+2\overline{w})=25\\(z+w)(\overline{z}+\overline{w})=4\end{cases}$$
$\implies$
$$\begin{cases}4z\overline{z}+w\overline{w}-2w\overline{z}-2\overline{w}z=625\\z\overline{z}+4w\overline{w}+2w\overline{z}+2\overline{w}z=25\\z\overline{z}+w\overline{w}+w\overline{z}+\overline{w}z=4\end{cases}$$
$\implies$ (Adding first and second, adding $2\times$third and first)
$$\begin{cases}5z\overline{z}+5w\overline{w}=650\\6z\overline{z}+3w\overline{w}=633\end{cases}$$
$\implies$
$$\begin{cases}z\overline{z}+w\overline{w}=130\\2z\overline{z}+w\overline{w}=211\end{cases}$$
$\implies$
$$z\overline{z}=81$$

$\implies$
$$|z|=9$$

---

Now that I've sorted out my own silly errors, it appears my answer agrees with yours. It was marked wrong possibly because it wasn't completely simplified?

Comment: I think you mean $$\begin{cases}(2z-w)(2\overline{z}-\overline{w})=625\\(z+2w)(\overline{z}+2\overline{w})=25\\(z+w)(\overline{z}+\overline{w})=4\end{cases}$$

Comment: Oh jeez. Woops.

Comment: Actually I do get the same answer as OP using your method.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Yep - and I agree too.

Answer (score 2):

I was curious if there was a valid solution to the triangle inequality.

$5(z+w) -3(z+2w) = 2z - w\\
|5(z+w)| + |3(z+2w)| \ge |5(z+w) -3(z+2w)| = |2z - w|\\
|5(z+w)| + |3(z+2w)| \ge |5(z+w) -3(z+2w)| = |2z - w|\\
10 + 15 \ge 25$

Now, since $10 + 15 = 25$

that suggests that $(z+w), (z+2w), (2z - w)$ all lie on the same line.

Which further suggests that $z,w$ lie on the same line, and we can just use real numbers.

$|18 + 7| = 25\\
|9-14| =5 \\
|9-7| =2 $

Answer (score 0):

We may assume $z$ real and then have
$$\eqalign{4z^2-2z(w+\bar w)+w\bar w&=625 \cr
z^2+z(w+\bar w)+w\bar w&=4\cr
z^2+2z(w+\bar w)+4w\bar w&=25\ .\cr}$$
Multiply these equations by $2$, $10$, and $-3$, then add. You  obtain $15z^2=1215$, which implies $|z|=9$.